# how to set the number of cards in a row in bootstrap carousel

Tags: jquery, css, bootstrap-4, carousel

inside a container, when I gave col-md-3 on each carousel-item 4 cards are shown at a time.
but what I want is to display two card on a row on medium screens (col-md-6) and 3 cards on larger and extra large screens (col-lg-4). also one card on mobile screens (xs).

I have tried col-lg-4 on each item but it doesn't work as expected. how can I solve this?

html

```
<!------ Include the above in your HEAD tag ---------->




<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./ashik.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div id="carouselExample" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="9000">
            <div class="carousel-inner row w-100 mx-auto" role="listbox">
                <div class="carousel-item col-md-3  active">
                   <div class="panel panel-default">
                      <div class="panel-thumbnail">
                        <a href="#" title="image 1" class="thumb">
                          <img class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" src="//via.placeholder.com/600x400?text=1" alt="slide 1">
                        </a>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item col-md-3 ">
                   <div class="panel panel-default">
                      <div class="panel-thumbnail">
                        <a href="#" title="image 3" class="thumb">
                         <img class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" src="//via.placeholder.com/600x400?text=2" alt="slide 2">
                        </a>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item col-md-3 ">
                   <div class="panel panel-default">
                      <div class="panel-thumbnail">
                        <a href="#" title="image 4" class="thumb">
                         <img class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" src="//via.placeholder.com/600x400?text=3" alt="slide 3">
                        </a>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item col-md-3 ">
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                      <div class="panel-thumbnail">
                        <a href="#" title="image 5" class="thumb">
                         <img class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" src="//via.placeholder.com/600x400?text=4" alt="slide 4">
                        </a>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item col-md-3 ">
                  <div class="panel panel-default">
                      <div class="panel-thumbnail">
                        <a href="#" title="image 6" class="thumb">
                          <img class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" src="//via.placeholder.com/600x400?text=5" alt="slide 5">
                        </a>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item col-md-3 ">
                   <div class="panel panel-default">
                      <div class="panel-thumbnail">
                        <a href="#" title="image 7" class="thumb">
                          <img class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" src="//via.placeholder.com/600x400?text=6" alt="slide 6">
                        </a>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item col-md-3 ">
                   <div class="panel panel-default">
                      <div class="panel-thumbnail">
                        <a href="#" title="image 8" class="thumb">
                          <img class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" src="//via.placeholder.com/600x400?text=7" alt="slide 7">
                        </a>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                 <div class="carousel-item col-md-3">
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                      <div class="panel-thumbnail">
                        <a href="#" title="image 2" class="thumb">
                         <img class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" src="//via.placeholder.com/600x400?text=8" alt="slide 8">
                        </a>
                      </div>
                      
                    </div>
                </div>
                
            </div>
            <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExample" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
            </a>
            <a class="carousel-control-next text-faded" href="#carouselExample" role="button" data-slide="next">
                <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>


<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<!-- <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> -->

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-Fy6S3B9q64WdZWQUiU+q4/2Lc9npb8tCaSX9FK7E8HnRr0Jz8D6OP9dO5Vg3Q9ct" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="./ashik.js"></script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

js

```
$('#carouselExample').on('slide.bs.carousel', function (e) {

  
    var $e = $(e.relatedTarget);
    var idx = $e.index();
    var itemsPerSlide = 4;
    var totalItems = $('.carousel-item').length;
    
    if (idx >= totalItems-(itemsPerSlide-1)) {
        var it = itemsPerSlide - (totalItems - idx);
        console.log({it});
        for (var i=0; i<it; i++) {
            // append slides to end
            if (e.direction=="left") {
                $('.carousel-item').eq(i).appendTo('.carousel-inner');
            }
            else {
                $('.carousel-item').eq(0).appendTo('.carousel-inner');
            }
        }
    }
});


  $('#carouselExample').carousel({ 
                interval: false,
        });


  $(document).ready(function() {
/* show lightbox when clicking a thumbnail */
    $('a.thumb').click(function(event){
      event.preventDefault();
      var content = $('.modal-body');
      content.empty();
        var title = $(this).attr("title");
        $('.modal-title').html(title);        
        content.html($(this).html());
        $(".modal-profile").modal({show:true});
    });

  });
```

Comment: For bootstrap, you should give it classes for each of the different sizes at the same time, eg `<div class='col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-xs-12'>`.  Here's an example - resize/zoom the screen/output panel to different sizes: https://jsfiddle.net/qu15tLx8/   What carousel does / how it handles that is anyone's guess...

Comment: I have tried that. but when I use `col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-xs-12` in larger screens two row is generated. where in first row there are 3 cards and in second row there are 1 cards which I dont want

Comment: Maybe you want `col-lg-3`?  But "3 cards in a row" is exactly what you've said you *do* want: "*and 3 cards on larger and extra large screens (col-lg-4)*"